# How to get schema or schema ID of JsonNode when using KafkaJsonSchemaSerde

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, jsonschema, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I am developing a Kafka Streams application consuming a topic with JSON Schema events. Following code works fine to consume the data properly according to documentation:

```
        ...
        serdeConfig.put(KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializerConfig.JSON_VALUE_TYPE, "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode");
        
        final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = new KafkaJsonSchemaSerde<>();
        jsonSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        
        
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC, Consumed.with(stringSerde, jsonSerde))
            .foreach((k, v) -> {
                System.out.println(v.toString());
        });
```

Now I do have a generic object `JsonNode`, similar to `GenericRecord` I would have in case of AVRO. What I need now is the *schema ID* of the consumed records. This information has to exist somewhere, since it is required to successfully parse the records (which has been done).

Where do I find this information?

I've tried using `JsonSchemaUtils` without success. Either of those functions returns junk, so I assume this is not the correct way:

```
JsonSchemaUtils.getSchema(v).name()
JsonSchemaUtils.getSchema(v).toString()
JsonSchemaUtils.getSchema(v).metadata().toString()
JsonSchemaUtils.getSchema(v).canonicalString()
JsonSchemaUtils.getSchema(v).rawSchema().getId()
```

The `JsonNode` class does not offer any possibility to retrieve a potential schema and it's also not part of the payload (in form of an envelope e.g.)